# Interpreting the version details for KDE

Tags: fedora, kde

If I do a `kded -version` on a terminal,
 this is what I get:

```
Qt: 3.3.8b
KDE: 3.5.10-21.fc12 Fedora
KDE Daemon: $Id: kded.cpp 711061 2007-09-11 09:42:51Z tpatzig $
```

**What does all this info mean/convey?**

specially the third line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is an underlying GUI framework. This KDE installation uses Qt 3.3.8b (Does b stand for 'beta'?)

This KDE installation is KDE version 3.5.10 (the latest in KDE 3.5 series) -21.fc12 is a vendor patch level. Red Hat made some 21 minor changes to it during preparation of Fedora Core 12.

KDE Daemon, a single component of KDE, uses information about the latest change made to it in the SVN repository (the main place where KDE developers do their work). It is a version that was commited by developer tpatzig in 2007. 711061 is a SVN commit number. Z in the timestamp means ZULU, the time zone.